# Using subquery for filtering with IN throws wrong data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, subquery, where-clause

In the last few days I saw behavior in an MS SQL server script.
Can you please have a look at this?

Version: Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8

'''
begin

```
declare @dataFrom table
(   
      DT_RECORD_ID numeric(9,0)
    , COMPANY nvarchar(25)
)

insert into @dataFrom
select top 10 RECORD_ID, COMPANY
from TABLE_WITH_DATA
where company = 'NAMEOFBIGCOMPANY'

-- 1 correct data
-- this will select only entries from TABLE_WITH_DATA are in the @dataFrom
select RECORD_ID, COMPANY
from TABLE_WITH_DATA
where RECORD_ID IN (SELECT DT_RECORD_ID from @dataFrom)

-- 2 too much data
-- this will select all entries from TABLE_WITH_DATA 
select RECORD_ID, COMPANY
from TABLE_WITH_DATA
where RECORD_ID IN (SELECT RECORD_ID from @dataFrom)    -- have a look at the "wrong" field RECORD_ID instead of DT_RECORD_ID
                                                        -- here there should come up an error 
                                                        -- because RECORD_ID is not known in @dataFrom
-- this throws an error
-- SELECT RECORD_ID from @dataFrom
```

end
'''

The --2 second select is resulting in all data from the TABLE_WITH_DATA but, even when the subquery field is the same name as in the upper select, it should result in an error.

Using this with updated statements, all rows in the table will be updated.
I know what I am talking about ;-)

Do you have experiences with this too? Is it a bug or a feature?

Thanks!

Comment: Since you're referencing `TABLE_WITH_DATA.RECORD_ID` inside `(SELECT RECORD_ID from @dataFrom)` you're effectively doing a join on all records with a matching `RECORD_ID` - which is all records.

Comment: Tip: Always using table names or aliases when using subqueries or joins helps to prevent these mistakes, e.g. `select T.A, T.B from T where T.C in ( select Y.X from Y where Y.ShoeSize = 42 );`. As your queries get larger it also makes it easier to see where data comes from, thus making maintenance easier.